# Function works with inferred lifetime but not explicit lifetime

Tags: rust, lifetime

In this code:

```rust
struct Obj<'a> {
    inside: &'a mut i32
}

fn take_and_return<'o>(obj: Obj<'o>) -> Obj<'o> {
    obj
}

fn run_me_1() {
    let mut v = 42;
    let s: Obj<'_> = Obj {
        inside: &mut v
    };
    take_and_return(s);
}
```

I wanted to introduce named lifetime for `s` in `run_me_1`.

I used Rust Analyzer's suggestion:

```rust
fn run_me_2<'a>() {
    let mut v = 42;
    let s: Obj<'a> = Obj {
        inside: &mut v
    };
    take_and_return(s);
}
```

But then I got the following error:

```rust
error[E0597]: `v` does not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:20:11
   |
17 | fn run_me_2<'a>() {
   |             -- lifetime `'a` defined here
18 |     let mut v = 42;
19 |     let s: Obj<'a> = Obj {
   |            ------- type annotation requires that `v` is borrowed for `'a`
20 |         inside: &mut v
   |                 ^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
23 | }
   | - `v` dropped here while still borrowed
```

My understanding is that `take_and_return` takes ownership of `obj`, so `obj` must last forever, so `'o` must last forever. That explains why `run_me_2` fails to compile.

My questions are:

- Why does `run_me_1` compile?
- What did the inferrer put into that `'_` in `run_me_1`?
- How can I fix `run_me_2` so that it compiles?

[Playground link to code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7a566531063a65032f85cd83818cf47f)

Comment: I think this is a XY problem. Why do you need that generic lifetime parameter `'a` when you don't have any input parameters bounded by it ? If you are not using it, then just remove it - problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

> My understanding is that take_and_return takes ownership of `obj`, so `obj` must last forever, so `'o` must last forever.

That kind of statement is true if the value is owned *and* has a `'static` lifetime bound, typically expressed as `T: 'static`. `take_and_return` doesn't require `T: 'static`, it takes a concrete type associated with a lifetime `'o` which it must not outlive (because it contains a reference with that lifetime).

`run_me_1` compiles not because the object is static, but because the variable `v` clearly outlives the value returned by `take_and_return`, which is immediately dropped, while `v` is still live. If you modified `run_me_1` so that the value returned by `take_and_return()` actually outlived `v`, it would fail to compile too. For example:

```
fn run_me_1_modified() {
    let x;
    {
        let mut v = 42;
        let s: Obj<'_> = Obj { inside: &mut v };
        x = take_and_return(s);
    }
    println!("{:p}", x.inside);  // or use x in any other way
}
```

> What did the inferrer put into that `'_` in `run_me_1`?

It put an anonymous lifetime corresponding to the part of the source where `v` is live.

`run_me_2()` is a different beast. It basically says, "I will let my caller choose any lifetime it wishes, and then I'll create an `Obj` associated with *that* lifetime, after which I'll pass it to `take_and_return()`, get an `Obj` with the same lifetime back, and destroy it. This can't be right because `Obj { &mut v }` clearly requires that the lifetime specified by `Obj` be a subset of the lifetime of `v`. But we're technically allowing our caller to choose the lifetime of `obj`, so it might as well call us with `run_me_2<'static>`.

Note that a declaration like `fn run_me_2<'a>() { ... }` doesn't make too much sense because only the static lifetime can be named without referring to a previously defined value. Normally lifetimes are connecting to existing values. The canonical example is something like:

```
fn search<'a, 'b>(haystack: &'a str, needle: &'b str) -> Option<&'a str>
```

...which says that the return value will be coming from `haystack`, and not from `needle`. On the other hand, `fn run_me_2<'a>()` is almost useless because it doesn't allow the caller to choose a useful lifetime based on a value it cares about, but only to provide `'static` as the only possible name.

> How can I fix `run_me_2` so that it compiles?

If you insist on having a *named* lifetime for `Obj`, then you need to introduce a function that receives a value connected to that lifetime. For example, you could pass the reference to the variable to an inner function:

```
fn run_me_2() {
    fn inner_fn<'a>(r: &'a mut i32) {
        let s: Obj<'a> = Obj {
            inside: r,
        };
        take_and_return(s);
    }
    let mut v = 42;
    inner_fn(&mut v);
}
```